# Understanding the use of か

Tags: particle-か

> 僕は山崎先生が昨日何を言ったか忘れてしまった

I don't understand what is that か doing in this sentence I mean, It should be an を but there's already one but anyways I don't think this is related to the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to break this sentence down is like this:

僕は　[山崎先生が昨日何を言ったか]　忘れてしまった。
I forgot [what Yamazaki-sensei said yesterday].

The か marks the clause as an embedded question that the main verb bears on, and this sentence is great example of the standard pattern. You usually don't need を after an embedded question. Instead, you simply raise a question using an informal sentence structure (no polite です・ます) and then comment on it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But why 山崎先生が昨日何を言った is a embedded question?  I still dont get it

Comment: OKAY OKAY OKAY, I was just checking other questions of people having a similar problem as me with that partcicle and I just saw this comment: "From what I understand, か here indicates an embedded question. Like in English, "I know what you mean." And now I understand it completly, in my mother tongue we dont really have that kind of questions so it was weird for me. Thanks for your help anyways!!

Comment: Great! Yes, if you get stuck with one of these, just literally translate it as a question followed by an answer. So, here, it would be: "What did Yamazaki-sensei say yesterday? I forgot."